# problem with phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm sending email with phpmailer, everything is fine but when I recieve the email in the
part that has email from, I get Webmaster as I set it and in brackets I get the full googlemail email address. (i'm using google mail smtp) to send mail,

I was just wondering if I can hide the googlemail email address somehow.

I'd like the cs@beautylusthaves to show but that doesn't come up.

thanks

```
$mailer->From = 'cs@beautylusthaves.com'; 

$mailer->FromName = 'WebMaster';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNTESTED GUESS -- Allow Google to send mail on behalf?

- From your mail server, set cs@beautylusthaves.com to receive or forward e-mails
- Log in to google mail with the e-mail address you are using to SMTP authenticate with
- Settings - Accounts & Import - Send Mail As - add cs@beautylusthaves.com
- Once you've validated, remove the forward/receive if you want

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about Google mail - not about PHP nor PHPmailer.

I expect you'll find this a matter of policy by them. If you must, use a different SMTP service.

C.